# How do I parse Excel times into a different format using functions, without VBA?

Tags: excel, time

I have cells with data displaying in the following format: `6:00 PM`. In the formula Bar though, it's displaying as `6:00:00 PM` if that matters.

I'd like to parse them into the following format to load into Salesforce: `18:00:00.000Z`

I know how to do this manually by right clicking on the cells with data and formatting the fields, but is there a way to do this using Excel's functions and without VBA? I couldn't locate any functions for reformatting Time fields.

Comment: TEXT function perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Your time input: 6:00 PM

Excel formula:

```
=TEXT("input", "HH:MM:SS.000Z")
```

Result: 18:00:00.000Z

Comment: @chrisneilsen You are correct, I hadn't looked at this answer in a while. Thanks for the correction